# import nose error first time using nose package

Tags: python, nose

I am getting following error while mere importing nose using `import nose` :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    import nose
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\nose-master\nose\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\nose-master\nose\core.py", line 143
    print "%s version %s" % (os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), __version__)
```

I am new to python.

I have added path using `sys.path.append("C:\\Python32\\Lib\\site-packages\\nose-master")`

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback, not just a fragment; the part you've shown us doesn't even have the error message.

Comment: This is exactly I am seeing as it is in my IDLE editor. I think I am using python 3 and print statement has changed from earlier versions. Nose guys are still using earlier versions.

Comment: Also… how did you install `nose`? Did you follow some tutorial somewhere? Because it seems very weird to have something named `nose-master` inside your site-packages, and to have to add it to the path that way. (When I just `pip install nose`, it ends up directly in `site-packages/nose`, as I'd expect.)

Comment: I am using windows OS.

Comment: Aha, you're using Python 2.x code in Python 3.x. Many packages use the `2to3` script to convert the source code on the fly during the install process. If you just copy the files around manually instead of installing, that will never happen.

Comment: how to run pip install command ? I am using IDLE editor.

Comment: I can't give you a tutorial on installing Python packages in SO comments/answers. But I'll try to give you enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't installed `nose` properly.

Like most packages, `nose` expects you to *install* it, not just use it out of the source in-place.

---

The official Python docs include [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/3/install/). However, that document may be a bit over-complicated for novices, especially Windows users, and it doesn't mention some of the newer, simpler options. But briefly:

- Download the source archive.
- Unzip it (or untar it, or whatever); often just double-clicking it on Windows will do this.
- Open a cmd (aka "DOS shell") window.
- `cd` to the source directory.
- `C:\Python32\python.exe setup.py install`

However, you will probably find it a lot easier to just automatically install things using [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/), or [pre-made binary packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#nose).

---

Having done this, `nose` should end up in the right place in `site-packages` so you don't need to do any `sys.path` munging in your code, and you should also end up with the command-line scripts like `nosetests` somewhere useful, like `C:\Python32\Scripts\`.

---

The specific problem in this case is that, as part of the installation process, `nose` figures out whether you're installing for Python 2.x or 3.x, and runs a tool called `2to3` to fix the code appropriately. Because you never did that step, you ended up with 2.x-specific code. As you guessed, it's the `print` statement vs. `print` function that bit you first—but if you got past that, there are dozens of other things that would fail similarly.

Comment: I downloaded it on my desktop and ran python command, it worked but it doesnt show up in site-packages. Earlier I copied everything in site-packages and then was running install command, it was running fine. But importing was giving this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nose
ImportError: No module named nose

Comment: @pokrate: Copying things manually into site-packages will work for a few packages, but not for most. You really need to get installation working. Life will be a lot easier if you can get `pip` installed and use that instead of using `setup.py` manually. Even better, set up `virtualenv`, and then install packages into its environments. Or, alternatively, the pre-built packages are very simple (and have the added advantage that if you ever need a C extension module, you won't need to know how to set up a compiler).